# Save Excel table in current folder

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save my current table as a text file in the same folder as the current workbook (that is open).

I use this code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & filename
```

For some reason it save the text file in the same folder as my personal.xlsb.

I use Office 2010

If this is not possible to do easily then maybe one can force Excel to open a browse window where I can pick where I want the file saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThisWorkbook points to the location where the code is written. In your case personal.xlsb.

If you want to save the table in the same directory as the active workbook, use ActiveWorkbook.path instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! OfCourse! Is there anyway to add a subfolder the ActiveWorkbook.path.

Comment: the path is just a string, so you can do what you did in the example. ActiveWorkbook.path & "\subfolder\" & filename

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

ChDir "C:\yourfolder"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"c:\yourfolder" & filename & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, _

In this example I have created a folder name "yourfolder" in my C drive. The created text file will save in C\yourfolder\filenane.txt

Hope this is helpful